# GWT - Mark parts of shared code as "server only"

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT app which contains, besides traditional "client" and "server" packages, also a "shared" package, which contains POJO DTOs that travel back/forth through RPC. I need to create some methods in those DTOs which should exist only on server-side (i.e. they should not be compiled to JS, because they'd use code which is not compile-able to JS), especially the `static()` method.

Is this possible in GWT (some attribute, ifdef, ...)?

Background:
I have some generic validators which require "registration" of the class to be validated (via a static method `register(Class<T>)`, and since I can't find any GWT init() method I'd put the registration in static constructors of the DTOs, so when (if) the class gets loaded it registers itself for validation.

Comment: So why isn't this code in the server package?

Comment: @stark Because these classes are shared between server and client packages. I need them on both sides, but some of the methods I need only on server side, and I'd like to somehow mark those methods as "not compilable to JS".

Comment: The code for a subclass doesn't have to be in the base class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A detailed discussion of this issue:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3769

Comment: What you have linked is a long discussion susceptible to link rot. Is there really no particular thing worth quoting?

Answer (score 1):

We had some similar issues with some DTO objects in a project recently.  We ended up splitting the data away from the methods, creating a second set of classes that contained static methods for dealing with the data.  As far as I can tell, there isn't any way to annotate methods in a class to prevent gwtc from trying to convert them to javascript.

Comment: It seems that they've added it, check latest answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Google implemented it in [r11570](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=11570).

Answer (score 0):

This was added in GWT 2.6. You can now use the @GwtIncompatible annotation to mark certain methods as incompatible with GWT. GWT will not try to compile these methods.